# What is happening to the value passed into the constructor after it falls out of scope?

Tags: c++, string, object-lifetime

I've been searching around for the answer to this and haven't found anything that was similar to my problem.

I have a class, let's call it `Foo`, that takes a `const char*` pointer in it's constructor. In my code, I need to create a new `Foo` with a `std::string`'s `.data()` as the parameter. The problem is, once the string falls out of scope, the value (or pointer, this is where I'm getting confused..) passed to Foo becomes invalid.

So now that the string is invalid, the Foo's `const char*` is invalid.

How can I pass the value of the string's data into `Foo` so that it won't become invalid once the string falls out of scope?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just make a copy of the string?  That way you know it will not disappear. If you don't know the const char * is going to be around for the duration of your class's life you need to copy it (or do something different like have the string wrapped in a reference counter)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be copying the string inside `Foo` to store it if you need it to last past the constructor's calling scope.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. (and by far the easier option) Just store it in an `std::string` in your class.
2. Allocate your own `char*` with `new[]`, and `strcpy` the data into your new `char*` in your constructor. Then you'll also need to define a destructor to `delete[]` `Foo`'s `char*`. Then, as is usually the case with the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), you'll need to define copy constructor and copy assignment operators as well to allocate their own new `char*` (and in the case of the copy assignment operator `delete[]` the old `char*`) and copy the the `char*` from the original `Foo`. Very easy to make a mistake and create a memory leak, or random crashing from trying to access freed memory.

x

```
class Foo {
    char* x;
    Foo(const char* y) {
        copy(y);
    }
    Foo(const Foo &f) {
        copy(f.x);
    }
    Foo& operator= (const Foo f) {
        cleanup();
        copy(f.x);
    }
    ~Foo() {
        cleanup();
    }
    bool copy(const char* y) {
       int len = strlen(y);
       try {
           x = new char[len+1]; //+1 for NULL
       } catch (std::bad_alloc ex) {
           //log failure to allocate memory
           return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
    void cleanup() {
        if (x) {
            delete[] x;
        }
        x = NULL;
    }
};
```

There's a good chance I left out something as this is off the top of my head, but I'm sure someone will be kind enough to point it out in the comments.

Also, using the `shared_ptr` from Boost may make your life easier for option #2, but I don't have much experience with it, and it might be a little heavy to use for just a small project.

And one more comment. You should really be using [`string.c_str`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) as well (as opposed to [`string.data`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/)) as it adds the NULL character you'll need.

Comment: It seems a lot less complicated to just store it as a string, I will try that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just giving the description won't help to decipher what wrong is going on in your code. `std::string::data()` returns the pointer to the beginning character of the array of characters. As long as the memory location passed doesn't go invalid, both the class member and the passed parameter point to the same location. If you see that, the passed parameter goes out of scope( i.e., it is no more valid ) then your class member becomes a dangling pointer. In that case, better to do a copy of the passed string. This should give you an idea -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
    const char* temp;

    public:
    Foo( const char* temp_ ) : temp(temp_) {}
    void check( )
    {
            while( *temp != '\0' ){
                std::cout << *temp ;
                ++temp;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string str = "I am a string";

    Foo *obj = new Foo( str.data() );

    obj->check();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** I am a string
[IdeOne](http://ideone.com/X0S0m). Hope this helps !

Comment: Nope, won't work. Add this after the new Foo line in main: `str[3] = 'X';`. Now see what the output is. The address to the internal data of the string that is being stored will be invalid to access as soon as the string is destructed and `free`s that data.

Comment: The question does have enough data.  If you are passed a pointer in the ctor, how do you do something w/ the pointer so you don't get dangling references.  "better to do a copy of the passed string" is correct, and is the same answer as the previous two.

Comment: This did help me understand what was going on internally with the pointers. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt B. Though your question has enough data to say what you are doing, it would be easy to see where the wrong is going on if the actual code is posted. Welcome to the world of Pointers ( I am learning pointers too ... ).

Answer (score 0):

Copy it. In a refcount friendly language you would "retain" the string. But this is C++. You have a high risk of dangling pointers if you do not copy it.

```
class Foo
{
 public:
   Foo(const char*  _data) 
   { 
      mData = new char[strlen(_data) + 1];
      strcpy(mData, _data); 
   }
   Foo& operator=(const Foo& _other) { /* deep copy string */ } 
   Foo(const Foo& _other) { /* deep copy string */ }
   ~Foo() { delete[] mData; }
 private:
   char* mData;
};
```

or

```
class Foo
{
 public:
   Foo(const char* _data) : mData(_data) { }
 private:
   std::string mData;
};
```

or

```
class Foo
{
 public:
   Foo(const std::string& _data) : mData(_data) { }
 private:
   std::string mData;
};
```

As you can see, the `std::string` option is easier.

Comment: I tried something like your first option after seeing Rob's answer and it seems that using std::strcpy with the destination being unintialized gives me an eror?

Comment: Rule of three -- you'll need to define the copy constructor and copy assignment operators as well unless you're absolutely 100% sure that you're not using them anywhere (and will never use them in the future).

Comment: @Matt B.: I actually forgot to allocate the char array when I first posted the answer. I edited the code. It should work now. And user470379 is right, you would need to implement a copy constructor and copy assignment operator so it doesn't make a shallow copy of the string when someone make fooA = fooB;. You don't have to if you pick the std::string option though.

Comment: It's more than just not creating a shallow copy, if you don't implement them and you do create a copy, then both destructors will try to `delete` the same memory.